# validate input with name containing brackets in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, symfony, ng-class

I have a form input with names containing brackets, e.g.:

```
<form name="my_form">  
    <input type="text" name="my_form[email]" ng-model="email" ng-class="'mycssclass': my_form.my_form[email].$invalid">
</form>
```

So, the problem is that Angular is not applying that css class because of the name of my input (my_form[email]), is that the correct notation to reference my input in Angular.

Here's is a plunk:
http://plnkr.co/edit/t7PEilV9maNYGnVYnTDc?p=preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to reference an input with a name containing brackets is using brackets notation, like this:

```
my_form['my_form[email]'].$invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ng-model` attribute in your input. It bind the content of a field with a value in the `$scope`. You also need to pass a Javascript Object to the `ng-class` directive. In your example it would be :

```
<form name="my_form">  
    <input type="text" ng-model="my_form.email" ng-class="{'mycssclass': my_form.email.$invalid}">
</form>
```

Don't hesitate to look at the examples in the [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) and [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive documentation.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't add the ng-model directive in my example, but I'm using it, that's not the problem. My problem is the input name containing braces.

Comment: Could you provide a plunkr of your problem ?

Comment: Here is the corrected version of your plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/tz0Bmbt7HNmEOiFxXwgG?p=preview. Basically, you needed to change the name of the input to `email` and the `error` class trigger to `my_form.email.$invalid`.

Comment: obviously, if I change the name of the input it should work... but in my case I could not change the name of the input.